# About interface between motherboard and CPU

Tags: cpu, motherboard

Hmmm, it seems a stupid question.

I have bought one CPU which is i7 7800x, the supported interface is LGA 2066.
I have also bought one motherboard which is Z370 AORUS GAMING 3, the supported interface is LGA 1151.

The sad news is, I failed to install CPU on that motherboard, so here comes the question, is LGA 2066 compatible with LGA 1151? If not, what can I do beside change motherboard or CPU? Is there any adapter?

Comment: No adapters, you need to match the socket to the processor.

Comment: @Moab Hmmm, it's really a sad news.

Comment: It is also possible that by trying to fit incompatible parts together that you may have damaged one or both of the parts. CPU and motherboard sockets need to match.

Comment: It's not just the physical socket - the chipset / BIOS also needs to support the processor. e.g: Intel Z270 chipset doesn't support 8th Gen processors. [ref](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/intel-coffee-lake-z270-z370-motherboard,35554.html)

Comment: @Mokubai I decided to replace my mother board, I thought CPU and mother board have the same socket, lol.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about attempting to get incompatible parts to work with one another.  The author purchased incompatible, this question as it's currently written, does not really have an answer that would be helpful to anyone but the author.

Comment: @Ramhound I can't agree with your opinion cause there may be another guy that doesn't know the interface difference. We couldn't assume how users can get help from StackExchange. I always get help from StackExchange with not directly related thread.

Comment: @Gearon - Of course you don't agree, it's your question, nobody wants their question closed.  If this question isn't closed, it should be protected, to avoid low-quality answers that repeat the same information already stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, no adapters. Decades ago, there were, but CPUs run at such high clock speeds that creating a reliable socket adapter is not worth developing for the number which would sell.